# Pass argument through .bat file to .exe file that converted by 'PyInstaller'

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, ffmpeg, pyinstaller

I got an error when passing arguments through .bat file to .exe file that converted by PyInstaller
In my python script I import the following libraries:

```
import time
from contextlib import closing
from PIL import Image
import subprocess
from audiotsm import phasevocoder
from audiotsm.io.wav import WavReader, WavWriter
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np
import re
import math
from shutil import copyfile, rmtree
import os
import argparse
from pytube import YouTube
import cv2
from datetime import datetime
import datetime
import os.path
import shutil
import webbrowser
```

and this is my .bat file content:

```
mode con: cols=100 lines=40
@echo off
COLOR 0A
title VideoCuts 
:LOOP
if "%~1"=="" goto :END
ShortCut.exe --input_file "%~1" --silent_threshold 0.1 --silent_speed 9999999.00 --frame_margin 5 --sample_rate 48000 --frame_quality 1 --output_file "%~n1_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%_videocuts.mp4"
pause
```

I also tested using this .bat file:

```
ShortCut.exe --input_file="%~1" --silent_threshold=0.1 --silent_speed=9999999.00 --frame_margin=5 --sample_rate=48000 --frame_quality=1 --output_file="videocuts.mp4"
```

[this is my error message images during processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZloA.png)

Comment: and if you run the .exe without the .bat ?

Comment: the .exe file will not run properly because they have to have args pass through it

Comment: but my .py scrypt run properly in pycharm ide

Comment: @AyoubOcarina Can you open a command shell on Windows (cmd) and run the pyinstaller created executable in it. It should give a clearer error message

Comment: @VikramadityaGaonkar its give same error msg

Comment: @Compo thank you I’m are drinking by now! Relax!

Comment: Without using the fully qualified path to `ShortCut.exe`, or ensuring that you're running with the correct working directory, _which isn't set in your batch file_, or showing is what exactly the content `%1` is, you have not provided sufficient information for us to assist you.

Comment: @AyoubOcarina I think there are 2 ways to look at this problem:

Comment: Solved, the problem was in my exe file, I forget to add consol command to pyinstaller

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to answer questions when you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Do an echo of the command inside the bat script. For example, in your bat file, write another line just before you execute the `ShortCut.exe`

`echo "ShortCut.exe --input_file="%~1" --silent_threshold=0.1 --silent_speed=9999999.00 --frame_margin=5 --sample_rate=48000 --frame_quality=1 --output_file="videocuts.mp4""`

This will provide you with information if the executables are being called with the correct arguments. 
Depending on how you have implemented it in the py file, there might be an issue of finding this input file and `echo`ing the command before running it might be the perfect way to solve it.

As the [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/runtime-information.html#run-time-information) documentation mentions, you can also write if conditions for when the executable is frozen (Exe form) and when it will run from the IDE

```
import sys
if getattr( sys, 'frozen', False ) :
    # running in a exe form
else :
    # running on your IDE (eg. Pycharm)
```

Comment: Solved, the problem was in my exe file, I forget  to add consol command to pyinstaller

Comment: Great to know.
If this answer helped you resolve your question, you can mark it as "solved"